# Is it faster to save/delete entities asynchronously in Objectify?

Tags: objectify

Is it faster to save/delete entities asynchronously in Objectify?

For example, if updating an entity and wanting to return a response to a client quickly, would it be better to save the entity asynchronously and return a success status?

```
ofy().save().entity(thing1);         // asynchronous
ofy().save().entity(thing1).now();   // synchronous
```

edit:

Which is faster:

```
ofy().save().entity(thing1); // asynchronous
ofy().save().entity(thing2); // asynchronous
ofy().save().entity(thing3); // asynchronous
// Return true
```

Versus:

```
ofy().save().entity(thing1).now();   // synchronous
ofy().save().entity(thing2).now();   // synchronous
ofy().save().entity(thing3).now();   // synchronous
// Return true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asynchronous operations only help you run operations in parallel. You could load several things at once, then materialize the results and use the data. In the case of your edited example, yes the async version will be faster because the operations will complete in parallel. Although, it will probably be about the same speed as doing a single batch save:

```
 ofy().save().entities(thing1, thing2, thing3).now();
```

All async operations complete at the end of the request. If you're just saving one thing and returning, performance will be identical sync or async.

Comment: I should have been clearer in my question: What if there are multiple operations in a row such as in my edited question. Would the application be waiting for those sync operations to finish before returning? Maybe there would be some delay - could be micro-seconds but every micro-second counts!

Comment: Updated my answer.